# Get Database column xml and save it on local drive in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I have a table in which a column contains XML Data. I need to fetch the whole XML Data and save it on my local drive.

I didnt find any respective/specific solution for this.

Can anybody help me in this.

Table Name : Status
Colums: Id(int), Version (int), MaifestXML(xml)

I need to pull the Manifest Column data and save on local drive.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for help on how to query a database?

Comment: Same as getting string value.

Comment: @Ulric No, actually, I can query it, but its in XML format so what I should do after getting it in code and how to save it as xml file (eg:agent1.xml)

Answer (score 0):

If your XML is not valid, LoadXML will throw an error

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(yourQueryResult);
xdoc.Save(@"yourPath\yourFileName.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.Xml.Linq and then do the following:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstring);
    doc.Save("yourxmlfilename.xml");
```